# Flask redirect(urlfor()) doesn't work why?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login, flask-admin

```
@app.route('/result',methods=['GET','POST'])

def result(res):

    return render_template('public/inherit.html',res=res)

@app.route('/',methods=["POST","GET"])

def index():

    if request.method == "POST":
        a = 12
        redirect(url_for('result',res=a))
    return render_template('public/index.html'
```

> index.html

```
    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">
        <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

> inherit.html

```
<p>{{ res }}<p>
```

Comment: Please add some more details to your question. Also, mention if you are getting an error on some line?

Comment: redirect(url_for('result',res=a)) @Zeeshan this line bro  They can't return nothing

Comment: @Zeeshan  I also try return(redirect(url_for('result',res=a))) they have also error               TypeError: result() missing 1 required positional argument: 'res'

Comment: Try return redirect...

Comment: @IamMashed i tried but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
@app.route('/result',methods=['GET','POST'])
```

To

```
@app.route('/result/<res:int>',methods=['GET','POST'])
```

Comment: definitely use in flask like this <res:int>. If i use redirect the use this method otherwise no need